# How can I disable input and prevent it from opening in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuSnR.png)

How can I prevent any user from opening disabled input in the browser? Is there an easy way to do this or what should I do?

I use Vuejs in my project

I need to do this as a security measure
I couldn't find a solution

Comment: Would you tell me what you mean "opening disabled input in the browser"?
This is my testing code:
https://jsfiddle.net/2s0rug6q/1/

When I click on the text box, the browser does not respond.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the user cannot type on the input field, there are many ways and strategies you can do it and this can be tricky. Some of which that I can think of are as follows.

- Create a fake input field (For instance, a `<div>` styled to make it look like an `<input>` and the real `<input>` is on `display: none;` and display it whenever you want the `<input>` to be accessed.
- Add event listeners - one example is the `click` event and the `blur()` function:

Code for option 2:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" name="test" onfocus="preventFocus(event)"/>
</body>
<script>
function preventFocus(event) {
    event.target.blur();
}
</script>
```

The `onfocus` attribute of `<input>` fires when the user is about to type to the field while the `blur()` function removes the focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you don't want users to open devtool and inspect your input tag and remove `disable` property, it is impossible.

But security concerns can be satified by other methods such as validating it from submit event or through backend APIs.

Therefore you should approach it in other way.

Comment: Yes actually that's exactly what I'm talking about. Then I can only take precautions on the backend side.

Comment: maybe using javascript to disable it and then minify & obscure your js file would make it harder though. But any method doing so in client-side can be modified in theory.